# Connection timed out between docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have microservice app running on docker containers on Digitalocean Linux server.
 Locally they work fine and when I run them on server they are reachable from global network but they can't communicate with eachother, sayng **Connection Timed Out**.
Here is my Docker compose file

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  app.identityserver:
    image: registry.digitalocean.com/app/appidentityserver:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: App.IdentityServer/Dockerfile
    ports:
        - 6004:6004
        - 6005:6005
        #- 6004:443
        #- 6005:80
    container_name: appidentityserver
    environment:
        - ApiUrl=https://dev.mydomain.net:6000
        - ChatHubApiUrl=https://dev.mydomain.net:6100
        - MediaServerPath=https://dev.mydomain.net:6200
        - MailServiceUrl=https://dev.mydomain.net:6300
        - DefaultConnection=***
        - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
        - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:6004;http://+:6005
        - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=6004
        - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/app/sslCert/archive/cert1.pem
        - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__KeyPath=/app/sslCert/archive/privkey1.pem
    volumes:
        - /etc/letsencrypt/archive/dev.mydomain.net/:/app/sslCert/archive/

  app.api:
    image: registry.digitalocean.com/yekka/appapi:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: App/Dockerfile
    ports:
        - 6000:443
        #- 6001:80
    container_name: appapi
    environment:
        - IedntityServerUrl=https:dev.mydomain.net:6004
        - DefaultConnection=***
        - ChatHubPath=https://dev.mydomain.net:6100
        - MediaServerPath=https://dev.mydomain.net:6200
        - MailServicePath=https://dev.mydomain.net:6300
        - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
        - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+;http://+
        - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=6000
        - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/app/sslCert/archive/cert1.pem
        - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__KeyPath=/app/sslCert/archive/privkey1.pem
    volumes:
        - /etc/letsencrypt/archive/dev.mydomain.net/:/app/sslCert/archive/
    depends_on:
        - app.identityserver
```

Containers are on the same network, I can ping dev.mydomain.net from inside the container, but cannot hit container's with curl from inside the container. Also I can curl container from the host machine and vice versa.
Any ideas? I'm struggling with this for days, please help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just figured out that I haven't allowed container's ports in my UFW. It works now.

Comment: `sudo ufw disable` worked for me

Comment: I had the same problem, but in my case I have a VPN application which blocked local network sharing. I wasted half of a day on this, I hope this will help someone.